# Responsive text break

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Sorry for my bad english

I have problem with a responsive text can you help me ?

Look my website : http://idarya.fr/

The h2 on section "#Refugier" he break

I found solution for text cut :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  h2.section-heading2{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 250px;
  }
}
```

Thanks you for help :)

Now i need to hidden scroll bar. Do you have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure I understand. The only thing I can spot is the scroll bars on hover. Is that the issue you are having?

Comment: He has that too. The biggest problem in the "#refuge" section is that the h2 is cut on the phone

Answer (score -1):

If you are using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), 
you can use `<span class='visible-xs'><br/></span>` for making `<br/>` visible only when content width is 'xs'.